# Bounded Knapsack Problem in time O(NW) and space O(W)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to implement Bounded Knapsack Problem in O(NW) time and O(W) space, where N is number of items and W is capacity.

Bounded Knapsack Problem:

> There are N types of items (k_i copies of item i with weight w_i and cost c_i). Maximise total cost of items with weight less or equal to W.

My approach:

Use dynamic programming, create a table DP (rows are items, columns are capacities, DP[ i ][ j ] is max cost of items 1, 2,...,i with total weight not greater than j). The answer will be max of DP[N]. To complete row i we only need values from row i - 1, thus, we can calculate the last row by keeping track of only two rows. Hence, O(W) space.

[image]

Thus, using queue we can compute all cells of type DP[ i ][start + step * w_i] in one go, which implies that we can complete each row in O(W) time. (I use queue with O(1) amortised time max operation)

Here's my implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <deque>


class MyQueue {
    std::deque<int64_t> Deq_;
    std::deque<int64_t> Max_;
public:
    void push(int64_t element) {
        Deq_.push_back(element);
        while (!Max_.empty() and Max_.back() < element) {
            Max_.pop_back();
        }
        Max_.push_back(element);
        }
    void pop() {
        if (Max_.front() == Deq_.front()) {
            Max_.pop_front();
        }
        Deq_.pop_front();
    }

    int max() {
        return Max_.front();
    }
};


int main() {
    int number_of_items, capacity;
    std::cin >> number_of_items >> capacity;
    std::vector<int64_t> dp_cur(capacity + 1, 0);
    std::vector<int64_t> dp_prev(capacity + 1, 0);

    int64_t weight, cost, num;
    for (int item = 0; item < number_of_items; ++item) {
        dp_cur.swap(dp_prev);
        std::cin >> weight >> cost >> num;
        for (int start = 0; start < weight; ++start) {
            if (item == 0) {
                for (int step = 0; start + step * weight < capacity + 1; ++step) {
                    if (step == 0) {
                        dp_cur[start + step * weight] = 0;
                    } else if (step < num + 1) {
                        dp_cur[start + step * weight] = dp_cur[start + (step - 1) * weight] + cost;
                    } else {
                        dp_cur[start + step * weight] = dp_cur[start + (step - 1) * weight];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                MyQueue que;
                int64_t penalty = cost;
                for (int step = 0; start + step * weight < capacity + 1; ++step) {
                    penalty -= cost;
                    if (step > 1) {
                        if (step > num) {
                            que.pop();
                        }
                        dp_cur[start + step * weight] =
                                std::max(dp_prev[start + step * weight], que.max() - penalty);
                    } else if (step == 1) {
                        dp_cur[start + step * weight] =
                                std::max(dp_prev[start + step * weight], dp_cur[start] + cost);
                    } else {
                        dp_cur[start + step * weight] = dp_prev[start + step * weight];
                    }
                    que.push(dp_prev[start + step * weight] + penalty);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    std::cout << *std::max_element(dp_cur.begin(), dp_cur.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Input format:

First line contains N and W. Next N lines contain w_i, c_i, k_i.

The problem is that my implementation gives a wrong solution on some test (I cannot see the contents of it) and it seems that my second implementation (worse asymptotic) has the same problem. Could you please tell me where the problem might be or where I could find test cases? I only found [this problem](https://dmoj.ca/problem/knapsack), but my (adapted) solution passes all tests.

Comment: So the question basically is "here's my code, it fails sometimes but I don't know when and how. Please debug it for me".... hmm, I don't see hope this will be am addition to the site. You should test your code better and run through it with a debugger.

Comment: That image is nigh unreadable.

Comment: @JHBonarius I assume that someone might know of problems or tests which I couldn't find. My other implementation has the same problem, so I cannot just generate random tests and check whether they have the same output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've updated the image.

Comment: Generate random tests, solve them using MILP solver or brute-force (until they are small). Compare with your solution.